# Как добавить данные в название файла?

Tags: java, android

Нужно добавить GPS данные в название файла. GPS данные я получаю из класса DataGP. Его содержание:

```
public class DataGPS extends Activity {

private LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {// В onCreate ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕМ TextView КОМПОНЕНТЫ  И ПОЛУЧАЕМ locationManager ЧЕРЕЗ КОТОРЫЙ И БУДЕМ РАБОТАТЬ
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

protected void onResume() {// В onResume ВЕШАЕМ СЛУШАТЕЛЯ НА ПРОВАЙДЕРА С ПОМОЩЬЮ МЕТОДА requestLocationUpdates
    super.onResume();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER/*ТИП ПРОВАЙДЕРА*/,// НА ВХОД ЕМУ ПОДАЁМ
            1000 * 10/*МИНИМАЛЬНОЕ ВРЕМЯ ЗАПРОСА КООРДИНАТ*/, 10/*РАСТОЯНИЕ ОТОЙДЯ НА КОТОРОЕ ОБНОВЛЯЮТСЯ КООРДИНАТЫ*/, locationListener);
  }

@Override
protected void onPause() {//ОТКЛЮЧАЕМ СЛУШАТЕЛЯ МЕТОДА removeUpdates
    super.onPause();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}

private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {//LocationListener СЛУШАТЕЛЬ РЕАЛИЗУЕТ ИНТЕРФЕЙС locationListener СО СЛЕДУЮЩИМИ МЕТОДАМИ

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {//МЕТОД onLocationChanged НОВЫЕ ДАННЫЕ О МЕСТО ПОЛОЖЕНИИ
        showLocation(location);                       //ЗДЕСЬ ВЫЗЫВАЕМ СВОЙ МЕТОД showLocation(location)КОТОРЫЙ НА ЭКРАНЕ ОТОБРОЗИТ ДАННЫЕ О МЕСТО ПОЛОЖЕНИИ
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {//УКАЗАНЫЙ ПРОВАЙДЕР БЫЛ ОТКЛЮЧОН ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЕМ

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {//УКАЗАНЫЙ ПРОВАЙДЕР БЫЛ ВКЛЮЧОН ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЕМ

    }


};

private void showLocation(Location location) {// НА ВХОД БЕРЁТ Location location ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕТ ЕГО МЕТОДОМ .getProvider()
    if (location == null)
        return;
   // location.getProvider();
    formatLocation(location);
}

private String formatLocation(Location location) {// НА ВХОД БЕРЁТ Location location
    if (location == null)                         //ЧЕТАЕТ ИЗ НЕГО ДАННЫЕ И ВЫДАЁТ СТРОКУ
        return "";                                //ШИРОТА, ДОЛГОТА, ВРЕМЯ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ
    return String.format(
            "lat = %1$.4f, lon = %2$.4f",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());/*, new Date(
                    location.getTime()));*/
}
```

Так добавляю в имя файла

```
DataGPS dataGPS = new DataGPS();
file = new File(directory.getPath() + "/" + "photo_"
                    + timeStamp + dataGPS + ".jpg");
```

В название файла есть дата, но в место широты и долготы получается вот такая ерунда:

```
photo_094127_28062016cod.ru.centre_v00.MainActivity$DataGPS@4222a6b8.jpg
```

Что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При приведении объекта к типу `String` вызывается его метод `toString()`. Стандартная реализация метода выглядит так

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Т.е. строковое представление объекта состоит из его имени и хэш-кода, что и видно в вашем примере.

Если класс `DataGPS` написан вами, то вы можете переопределить метод `toString` по вашему вкусу. Либо же, если исходники данного класса вам не доступны, при формировании имени файла явно вызывать `get` методы данного класса.